# Rails: Unpermitted parameters: id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http

I want use rails 4 as a server and post data to rails and then data is save to database. For this, I sen data by `http` and `update` method. But when data recieve in server and rails want to save data, I get `Unpermitted parameters: id` error. I post data by below code:

```
  $scope.updateRadif = function(index, ID){
        console.log(ID);
        RadifSecure.update(index, {bolouk_id: 1, id: ID}).$promise.then(function(data){
            //...
        })
            .catch(function (err) {
                //...

            })
    };
app.factory('RadifSecure', function($resource) {
    return $resource("/api/bolouks/:bolouk_id/radifs/:id", { bolouk_id: '@bolouk_id', id: "@id" },
        {
            'show':    { method: 'GET', isArray: false },
            'update':  { method: 'PUT' },
            'destroy': { method: 'DELETE' }
        }
    );
});
```

and I recieve data in rails server:

```
  def update
    @radif = Radif.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @radif.update_attributes(radif_params)
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.json { render json: @radif.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  private
  def radif_params
    params.require(:radif).permit(:bolouk_id, :describe, :price)
  end
```

When I check the server log, the data is recieve ccorrectly, but rails doesn't permit to save in database:

```
Started PUT "/api/bolouks/1/radifs/16?describe=sdsad&price=3423432" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-03 11:14:27 +0430
Processing by Api::V1::RadifsController#update as JSON
  Parameters: {"bolouk_id"=>"1", "id"=>"16", "describe"=>"sdsad", "price"=>"3423432", "radif"=>{"id"=>"16", "bolouk_id"=>"1"}}
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 7  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Radif Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "radifs".* FROM "radifs"  WHERE "radifs"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 16]]
Unpermitted parameters: id
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
Completed 204 No Content in 29ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I try other code to solve this problem, but I'm not successful.

```
def update
    @radif = Radif.find(params[:id])
    radif.update!(radif_params)
end
```

Any one can help me to solve this problem?

Comment: I do not know why you need to send id you can try permit `:id`  `params.require(:radif).permit(:bolouk_id, :describe, :price, :id)`

Comment: At first, I have to find `radif` in database by id and then update record. I do this before, but I get this error again: `Completed 204 No Content in 4ms`. and when I want update a record in database, database doesn't change `id` of record.